# How to update child dropdown after parent dropdown's selection changes?

Tags: flutter, widget

So I have a column of dropdowns, each dropdown a prerequisite of the dropdown below. When `Dropdown A` changes its value, I'd make an API call and populate `Dropdown B`, `Dropdown C`'s options are dependent on the value of B, and so on...

I accomplished this scenario fine, but the problem I'm having is when Dropdowns A to D have been selected, and I change the value of `Dropdown B`, Dropdowns C and D doesn't change its value.

SOS & TY

Comment: paste you code also

Answer (score 0):

Refer the given example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: _title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
    body: Center(
      child: MyStatefulWidget(),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

 /// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
 class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
 }

 /// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
 class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
 String dropdownValue = 'One';

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  iconSize: 24,
  elevation: 16,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue;
    });
  },
  items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```

}
}